# `Connection Refused` when running a Hive-Query within a Python script with Thrift

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, thrift

All,

I am trying to run a hive query within a python script using Thrift library for Python.
I am able to run queries that dont execute M/R like `create table`, and `select * from table` etc.
But when i execute query that execute M/R job (like `select * from table where...`), I get the following exception.

```
starting hive server...

Hive history file=/tmp/root/hive_job_log_root_201212171354_275968533.txt
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
java.net.ConnectException: Call to sp-rhel6-01/172.22.193.79:54311 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Job Submission failed with exception 'java.net.ConnectException(Call to sp-rhel6-01/172.22.193.79:54311 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
```

---

I have a multi node hadoop cluster, and my hive is installed in the namenode, I am running the python script on the same namenode too.

The python script is

```
from hive_service import ThriftHive
from thrift import Thrift
from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol

transport = TSocket.TSocket('172.22.193.79', 10000)
transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(transport)
protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)

client = ThriftHive.Client(protocol)
transport.open()

client.execute("select count(*) from example ")
print client.fetchAll();
transport.close()
```

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong?

-Sushant

Comment: What is the output of `jps` when the script is executed?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue. There was a cluster setup issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble completing `SELECT` queries, though I could complete `SHOW` and `DESCRIBE` queries.  The way I fixed this was by restarting the services on my cluster.
I am using Cloudera to manage my cluster, so the command I ran was `$ sudo /etc/init.d/cloudera-scm-agent hard_restart`.  I did not spend too much time debugging, but I am guessing the NN or JT crashed.  The interesting part is that I could still complete queries on the metadata.  My best guess is that the queries went straight to the metastore and did not have to touch the HDFS.  I need someone to confirm that though.