# Are there any python or scala tools to connect the spark/shark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, shark-sql

I want to use python or scala to connect shark server. But I didn't find any tools to do this.
Are there any libs(python or scala/java).
Thanks advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what do you mean by *connect* but both [shark](https://github.com/amplab/shark/wiki/Shark-User-Guide#spark-scala-shell-with-spark-bindings-advanced) and [spark](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/scala-programming-guide.html) speak scala:

```
$./bin/shark-shell
scala> val youngUsers = sql2rdd("SELECT * FROM users WHERE age < 20")
scala> println(youngUsers.count)
...
scala> val featureMatrix = youngUsers.map(extractFeatures(_))
scala> kmeans(featureMatrix)
```

In addition spark speaks [python](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/python-programming-guide.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run SQL queries using Shark, Shark's [sharkserver](https://github.com/amplab/shark/wiki/Shark-User-Guide#sharkserver) behaves like a regular Hive Thrift server, so you should be able to re-use existing Python methods for connecting to Hive, such as

- [Hive queries via Python client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491951/hive-queries-via-python-client)
- [Access Hive Data Using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722372/access-hive-data-using-python)

Shark Server also supports Hive's [JDBC interface](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveJDBCInterface), so you can use that to run queries from Scala or Java; just use the Shark Server's address in place of the Hive Server address.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. That's what I want to try.